# Content from web-site won't display in my logcat

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download content of some random web content to my Logcat. I already did this many time but now I am getting only `2020-05-17 13:24:20.850 24632-24632/com.example.jsondownload I/Rezultat URLa:: {` and nothing else.Content is some random JSON small sample and I want to show it in my logcat, and nothing else.
I added internet permission.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String string = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=6...3";
    DownloadAsync downloadAsync = new DownloadAsync();
    downloadAsync.execute(string);
}
public static class DownloadAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        StringBuilder rezultat = new StringBuilder();
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
        try {
            url = new URL(strings[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            int podaci = inputStreamReader.read();
            while (podaci!=-1){
                char trenutnoSlovoKojeSeCita = (char) podaci;
                rezultat.append(trenutnoSlovoKojeSeCita);
                podaci = inputStream.read();

            }
            return rezultat.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Neuspesno";
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Log.i("Rezultat URLa: ",s);
    }
}

}
```

I find a solution: I added BufferReader:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String string = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Belgrade&appid=6c5022949de1b8e8448bc7232238dcf3";
    DownloadAsync downloadAsync = new DownloadAsync();
    downloadAsync.execute(string);
}
public static class DownloadAsync extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        StringBuilder rezultat = new StringBuilder();
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
        try {
            url = new URL(strings[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line!=null){
                rezultat.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

            return rezultat.toString();
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Neuspesno " ;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String rezultat) {
        super.onPostExecute(rezultat);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(rezultat);
            String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                String main = jsonObject1.getString("main");
                String desc = jsonObject1.getString("description");
                Log.i("main: ",main);
                Log.i("description: ",desc);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think you just posted your own API key so you should get another one.

Comment: As a sanity check you could replace `return rezultat.toString();` with `return "success";` just to make sure the `AsyncTask` is working.

Comment: @user2740650 i replaced with "success" and it works fine.So AsyncTask i not a problem here

Comment: You should check that it's successful with something like `int code = httpURLConnection .getResponseCode();` `if (code != HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {`.  If it's not successful, there won't be anything to read.  I don't see anything wrong with your stream-reading code.

Comment: when i put your code  int code = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (code != HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    Log.i("SUccess: ", String.valueOf(inputStream));
                } else {
                    Log.i("Failed: ", String.valueOf(inputStream));
                }     second, failed log, is activated..why?

Comment: @user2740650 when i print value of podaci before while loop it shows number 123...but when i print value of podaci in my while loop it shows -1 and stop printig in my log...why is sowing -1???

Comment: Seems you got a single character in the data stream, but the important part is that you are NOT getting a `HTTP_OK` response.  Can you log what `code` is to help narrow it down?

Comment: the problem was in the StreamReader ... it read all the characters at once and by the time it got to the while loop it would have written to me that my data was -1 and read only the first character and then leave the loop...i added BufferedReader and it is all ok now

Comment: Please post a code fragment as an answer as it might help others.